# Sort the array of Objects by the specific key value

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

I have Array of object data which i want to sort objects of the Array by the specific key that is `favourite`. In the Array of fruits. it has some object of the fruits. I just want to sort according to the `favourite` key. if the key `favourite:true` inside object then this object will go to the top and  if `favourite:true` is found in the more than one object,then always  set top  of first object which found the `favourite:true` key.

Input data:

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    title: 'Banana',

  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: 'Mango',
    favourite:true
  },
{
  id:3,
  title: 'Apple',
},
]
```

expected Output data:

```
[
{
    id: 2,
    title: 'Mango',
    favourite:true
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    title: 'Banana',

  },
  
{
  id:3,
  title: 'Apple',
}
]
```

Answer (score 1):

What you could do, is instanciate a new array, based on the given input values:

```js
const favouritesFirst = [
  // Find all the favourite items & add them to the start
  ...input.filter(item => item.favourite),
  // Append all other "non favourite" items
  ...input.filter(item => !item.favourite),
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use filter function to find out favourite fruits.

```js
var arr = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: 'Banana',

  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: 'Mango',
    favourite:true
  },
    {
      id:3,
      title: 'Apple',
    },{
    id: 4,
    title: 'Orange',
    favourite:true
  }
];


// Filter  favourite fruits
var favoriteFruits = arr.filter(obj => obj.favourite == true);

// Filter non favourite fruits

var otherFruits = arr.filter(obj => obj.favourite !== true);

// Find sorted fruits

var sortedArr = favoriteFruits.concat(otherFruits);
```

Use **concat** functioon to join favourite and non favourite arrays. Favourite fruits will always stays at the top.

Answer (score -1):

```js
fruits.sort((a, b) => {
    if(a.favourite && !b.favourite) return 1;
    else if (!a.favourite && b.favourite) return -1;
    else return 0;
});
```

Comment: While this piece of code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn and eventually apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback/upvotes from users, when the code is explained.